# How to wrap some html with a CDATA tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cdata, html-sanitizing

How do you wrap some html in a element in a CDATA tag so it become 'sterilized' so to speak...

I've tried...

```
$(this).html( "<![CDATA[" + $(this).html() + "]]>" );
```

and

```
$(this).wrap("CDATA");
```

The first wraps it in save html entities so it's not a CDATA tag. And the second doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by making it *"'sterilized'"*?

Comment: Whatever you're trying there, CDATA belongs to XML, not HTML, especially not HTML5. You don't need to "sterilize" anything here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers only support CDATA markers in XHTML, so you need to:

1. Write XHTML.
2. Serve it as `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` so the browser doesn't push it through an HTML parser anyway.

(I only tested the above on Chrome, you can [see the results](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/21706039/)).

You'd be better off getting the browser to treat it as text instead of as HTML:

```
$(this).text( $(this).html() );
```